# Again and again... Pointer to member-function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Suppose:

```
class Parser
{
  public:
  void parser1(int a, int b, int c);
  void parser2(int d, int e, int f);
  void setupPtr();

  void (Parser::*ptrParser) (int param1, int param2, int param3);
}

Parser::setupPtr()
{
   if(bla bla)
   {
       ptrParser = &Parser::parser1;
   }
   else
   {
       ptrParser = &Parser::parser2;
   }
}
```

in main:

```
int main(argv, argc)
{
   Parser parser;
   parser.setupPtr();
// first case
   parser.ptrParser(some paramps); // error!    error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
// second case
   parser.*ptrParser(some paramps); // error!   'ptrParser' : undeclared identifier
// third case
   (parser.*ptrParser)(some paramps); // error!     'ptrParser' : undeclared identifier


}
```

Comment: You do realize that all your members in the class are `private` so you cannot access them from `main`?

Comment: sorry, edit code.. originaly its public

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? It's very possible you don't need function pointers at all.

Comment: 2Karl: I need firstly, to parse some raw data(parseFunc), than according to its type call different getcontentX functions. Parse function gets from 3party C-library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you change the `ptrParser` field to be public, you need to write `main` this way:

```
int main()
{
   Parser parser;
   parser.setupPtr();
   (parser .* (parser.ptrParser))(1, 2, 3);
   return 0;
}
```

Let's try to understand the line.

First, to call a pointer-to-member-function of type `void (Parser::*)(int, int, int)`, given an instance of `Parser` called `inst` and a pointer-to-member-function `func`, the syntax is:

```
(inst .* func)(x, y, z);
```

In our case, the instance is named `parser` and the pointer-to-member-function is stored in the `ptrParser` field of the `parser` class that is accessed with the `parser.ptrParser` syntax. Replacing it in the previous expression, this give us (adding parenthesis because I'm not sure of operator precedence):

```
(parser .* (parser.ptrParser))(x, y, z);
```

If instead of a reference or an object we have a pointer to a `Parser`, the syntax would be:

```
int main()
{
   Parser *parser = createAndInitializeParser();
   (parser ->* (parser->ptrParser))(1, 2, 3);
   markParserAsNotUsedDestroyIfNeeded(parser);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow! I'm shocked, but this compiled! Now i need to understood what it mean). Thanks!

Comment: this not trivial snippet, I didn't see that previously )

Answer (score 1):

Great intro/tutorial about function pointers in (almost) all shapes and sizes: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

I believe you are looking for part 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with this code.

1)  ptrParser is not assigned to anything.  You need to call Parser::setupPtr first.

2) ptrParser is a method pointer to a method which takes no parameters, meaning in short that you must define it to contain parameters.  I think you could still get away with it if you casted it before calling it, but better to keep such things simple.

Declaration for a method pointer for your particular example would be:

```
  void (Parser::*ptrParser) (int, int, int);
```

Comment: sorry for bit broken code, i wrote them on fly, and forget params in func-ptr definition. But question is still active.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest you to make a typedef of your function ptr type :

```
typedef void (Parser::*funcptr) (int , int , int );
```

and then create your contener :

```
class Parser
{
public:
typedef void (Parser::*funcptr) (int , int , int );

void parser1(int a, int b, int c);
void parser2(int d, int e, int f);
void setupPtr();

funcptr firstptr;
}
```

to set it :

```
firstptr = &Parser::parser1;
```

to call it :

```
Parser foo;
foo.setupPtr;
(foo.*(foo.firstptr))(1, 2, 3);
```

It's less difficult to understand, and you will be able to create funcptr array...